# Why does ZSH return "Command not found" error for my RVM gems?

Tags: rubygems, rvm, zsh

I used to run the default `bash` terminal that comes with Mac Os X Lion but have recently upgraded to `ZSH` with the `Oh My Zsh` addon.

Since then I get an odd error when using Ruby gems.

In essence all gems return a "Command not found" error even though they are installed.

---

Here is an example straight from my ZSH terminal:

1. Shows that the RVM ruby is running as it should.
2. `rvm list` shows my RVM ruby to be the default as I want it.
3. `rvm gem list` shows that my gems are installed, **note the `sass` gem** .
4. Running a simple `sass --watch` command returns `zsh: command not found: sass`.
5. Just in case it helps, my `$PATH` variable output.

   ```
   Jannis-Mac-Pro: /Volumes/Storage2/Sites/git/mathewhawley.com/static
   → which ruby
   /Users/jannis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

   Jannis-Mac-Pro: /Volumes/Storage2/Sites/git/mathewhawley.com/static
   → rvm list     

   rvm rubies

   =* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]

   # => - current
   # =* - current && default
   #  * - default


   Jannis-Mac-Pro: /Volumes/Storage2/Sites/git/mathewhawley.com/static
   → rvm gem list
   Please note that `rvm gem ...` is only an alias to `rvm do gem ...`,
    it might work different as in earlier versions of RVM and will be shortly removed!
    Also note that you do not have to prefix every command with `rvm`, they should just work by itself.
   `rvm do gem list` is deprecated, use `rvm all do gem list` or `rvm 1.9.2 do gem list` instead.

   *** LOCAL GEMS ***

   addressable (2.2.7, 2.2.6)
   chunky_png (1.2.5)
   compass (0.11.7, 0.11.6, 0.11.5)
   css_parser (1.2.6)
   fssm (0.2.8.1, 0.2.7)
   grid-coordinates (1.2.0)
   haml (3.1.4, 3.1.3)
   htmlentities (4.3.1)
   json (1.6.5)
   nokogiri (1.5.0)
   oily_png (1.0.2)
   premailer (1.7.3)
   rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
   rb-fsevent (0.9.0, 0.4.3.1)
   rdoc (3.12)
   rubygems-update (1.8.17, 1.8.15, 1.8.13, 1.8.11)
   sass (3.1.15, 3.1.12, 3.1.10)
   stitch (0.1.3.2)

   Jannis-Mac-Pro: /Volumes/Storage2/Sites/git/mathewhawley.com/static
   → sass --style compressed --watch scss:css
   zsh: correct 'sass' to 'case' [nyae]? n
   zsh: command not found: sass

   Jannis-Mac-Pro: /Volumes/Storage2/Sites/git/mathewhawley.com/static
   → echo $PATH
   /Users/jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/jannis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/jannis/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
   ```

If anyone has an idea of why everything appears to be running and be installed but then doesn't actually find and run the gem command I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to locate the binary manually in the appropriate gem directory. e.g.: /Users/jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sass-3.1.15/bin/. It should also be in your /Users/jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin. This way at least you can use it until you find a proper fix.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

check your rc files

- .zshenv
- .zshrc
- .zlogin
- .zprofile

most likely in one of those `PATH` is reset after RVM was sourced

also some oh-my-zsh plugins can break stuff, try disabling them and enabling one by one.

Comment: Hmm… first off all thanks for your answer! I went through all the files but the `PATH` isn't being reset and the only plugin I'm currently using is the `git` one which I've disabled and that didn't help either. In closer inspection though I noticed that I seem to be unable to set a default ruby gem for new terminal instances which is the problem. Using `rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --default` will set it to be the default but the moment I close and open a new terminal window `rvm list` will indicate that this version of ruby that should be default is not being used. Any ideas?

Comment: DOH! I found the cause, in my last line of the `.zshrc` file I had `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` without having the `export` at the beginning of the line. Now that this line reads `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` everything is fine and dandy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this was related to [ZSH complains about RVM __rvm_cleanse_variables: function definition file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585002/zsh-complains-about-rvm-rvm-cleanse-variables-function-definition-file-not-fo) , and following the instructions there solved it.

Answer (score 1):

follow the rvm install doc, i add 2 line in my ~/.zshrc

```
#add $PATH in path
export PATH="$PATH: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/m/Downloads/temp/bin:/Applications/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin:/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/m/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/m/Desktop/python/vlfeat/bin/maci64:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/m/bin/FDK/Tools/osx"
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
#rvm puby need this, get this file
source ~/.profile
```