# ZSH complains about RVM __rvm_cleanse_variables: function definition file not found

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, zsh

When using the latest ZSH and RVM on Mac OS X 10.7.4 ZSH complains about this:

`__rvm_cleanse_variables: function definition file not found`

Comment: This happens in Ubuntu too, after RVM update. @heracek's solution solved the issue.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

Running the following solved the problem:

`rm ~/.zcompdump*`

Note: The * is incase there are multiple .zcompdump files.

Comment: ZSH uses `compinit` to initialize completion for the current session. To speed up the running of `compinit`, it can be made to produce a dumped configuration which will be read in on future invocations. This dumped file is `.zcompdump` in the same directory as the startup files (i.e. `$ZDOTDIR` or `$HOME`).

Comment: Boom goes the dynamite.

Comment: searched for "whats 'zcompdump' for" while diagnosing the `__rvm_cleanse_variables` issue... two birds, one search. +1's to everyone.

Comment: just as a nitpick seems like you could remove the `-f` flag, doesn't seem necessary to bypass the remove file confirmation (if the user has it set in the first place)

Answer (score 109):

Sometime there is also `~/.zcompdump-<COMPUTER NAME>-<VERSION>` file, so use:

```
rm -f ~/.zcompdump*
```

Comment: Cheers, that was my issue :)

Comment: Do not forget to open a new shell.

Answer (score 7):

To disable the `.zcompdump*` file(s), you could look in your `.zshrc` (or `/etc/zsh/* files`) for `compinit` and add the `-D` flag.

This might be better than creating the files and deleting them at every login.

(source: http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/linux/zsh-doc/zsh_23.html)

Comment: But probably .zcompdump files have advantages and by deleting them it has side effects.

Answer (score 4):

My problem persisted even after the `compinit -D` and `rm -f ~/.zcompdump*`. I found [this github issue](http://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4787) and checked my .zplug directory and sure enough found some non-hidden zcompdump files (no preceding '.'). Deleted those and I was good to go. If you're using a zsh plugin manager like zgen or zplug, check their directories.

Comment: boy u saved day. for me along with `~/.zcomdump*`, need to remove `~/.antigen/.zcomdump*` too

Answer (score 1):

Add rm -f ~/.zcompdump{,.zwc} to .zlogin to automate it

Comment: or compinit -D if you don't want caching.